# Executing C# executable that uses Powershell execution is erroring out

Tags: c#, powershell, 64-bit, office365

I have c# web service invoking an external executable with parameters to run Powershell using runspace.

I have 64 bit machine and configured IIS to run 64 bit executable.

When Executable is called it does not find PowerShell commands, it appears that if I am running in 32 bit mode, appropriate 64 bit PowerShell cmdlets will not be found.

I am looking for some help on how to configure this.

1. I have compiled executable in 64 bit mode using Visual Studio.
2. I have configured IIS to run in 64 bit mode
3. I have Windows 2008 R2

This cmdlets are regarding Office365 user creation

When I execute New-MsolUse, it says you must execute Connect-MsolUser  my PowerShell does have appropriate connect call before New-MsolUser command.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean "I am running in 32 bit mode"?  You say the executable is compiled as x64.  The EXE hosting the PowerShell Runspace determines which PowerShell engine (32-bit or 64-bit) gets used.  Are you sure the Office365 cmdlets are 64-bit?  Fire up a 64-bit PowerShell prompt and see if you can see these cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

In the Project Properties > Compile > Advanced Compile Options page, try setting the Target CPU to 'Any CPU'.  See if this solves the problem.

Comment: I tried Any CPU and also tried with x64, nothing seem to work, my executable does gets executed but with errors. If I run the executable on command line it works just fine.